# subfolders in views/helpers zend

Tags: zend-framework, view, view-helpers

I want to create different folders insides my views/helpers and add my view helper classes inside them. But I am not able to access those classes.

What is the best way to do this?

I tried adjusting my application.ini file settings ... but no luck

This is what I have set inside my ini file:

```
resources.view.helperPath = APPLICATION_PATH "/views/helpers/models"
resources.view.helperPath = APPLICATION_PATH "/views/helpers/test"
```

`models` and `test` are the sub-folders inside my `/views/helpers` folder

Can anyone suggest a better solution?

Answer (score 2):

With your current setting in your `application.ini` you only add another path for the default view helpers from Zend (`Zend_View_Helper_`).

You have to specify the class prefix which you want to use:

```
; View_Helper_Models is the class prefix
resources.view.helperPath.View_Helper_Models = APPLICATION_PATH "/views/helpers/models"
; View_Helper_Test is the class prefix
resources.view.helperPath.View_Helper_Test = APPLICATION_PATH "/views/helpers/test"
```

Now the application knows how to map your class name to the path. Alternative you can enable this in your main `Bootstrap.php`:

```
protected function _initViewHelper()
{
   $this->bootstrap( 'view' );
   $this->_view = $this->getResource( 'view' );

   $this->_view->addHelperPath( APPLICATION_PATH . '/views/helpers/models',
                                'View_Helper_Models' );
   $this->_view->addHelperPath( APPLICATION_PATH . '/views/helpers/test',
                                'View_Helper_Test' );
}
```

**NOTE:** The path must be in the right case.

Answer (score 0):

In your config file add these two lines second line is your custom path to helpers

```
resources.view[] =    
resources.view.helperPath.Zend_View_Helper = APPLICATION_PATH "/../library/FolderA/FolderB/helpers"
```

While creating a Helper give the class name like this

```
<?php
class Zend_View_Helper_Foo extends Zend_View_Helper_Abstract
{
   public function foo(){
       echo 'hello world';
   }
}
```

and call that helper in any of your view files as `$this->foo();`

Answer (score -1):

I think that you need only put the correct name of your view helper classes!
For example, you create a file "Mine.php" inside APPLICATION_PATH "/views/helpers/models" and then you name the class as `class View_Helper_Models_Mine`

Hope this help.

Regards,
Ahmed B.